# Is there a way to limit the parameter type passed into a method?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to restrict the parameter accepted by a method to one specific user-defined class and haven't been able to find a way to do this so far.

Is there a way?

This is my code:

```
class Item {
    public:
        std::string name;  
        Item(std::string n) { name = n; }
}

class Container {

    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string description;
        std::vector<Item> contents;
    
    public:
        Container(std::string n, std::string des) {name = n; description = des;}

        void Container::addItem(Item item) {
            if (typeid(item) == typeid(Item)) {contents.push_back(item);}
        }
}

// code from test file:

WHEN("I try to add something which is not an Item.") {
    std::string helment = "helmet";
    std::vector<Item> contentsBefore = merchant.get_contents();
    merchant.addItem(helmet);    // here a string is added to class attribute "contents" via the above addItem method
    std::vector<Item> contentsAfter = merchant.get_contents();
    THEN("The container should not be updated to add the item.") {
        REQUIRE(contentsBefore == contentsAfter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know to be honest, I'm very new to C++. I have a class which has a string attribute and am trying to test a method of a second class so that it will only accept an object of the first class, but if I just try to pass a string into it, it accepts the inputted parameter.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows the string conversion you're describing.

Comment: Updated with some of the code, hopefully enough to show what's going on. Essentially the latter part is testing whether an object which is not of type `Item` can be passed into the method `addItem`. Currently `helmet` which is a string is being accepted by the method and being added to a vector of type `Item`

Comment: Do you really want the `addItem(string)` to silently be ignored? I would understand asking for a compile-time error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a class which has a string attribute and am trying to test a method of a second class so that it will only accept an object of the first class, but if I just try to pass a string into it, it accepts the inputted parameter.

No, it doesn't.

It *implicitly converts* the string parameter to an `Item` because the single-argument constructor works as a user-defined conversion. To prevent this, use the keyword `explicit`:

```
class Item {
    public:
        std::string name;  
        explicit Item(std::string n) { name = n; }
}
```

This means you can still create an `Item` from a `std::string` ... but only explicitly (ie, it disables the implicit conversion you don't want).

References for further reading:

1. [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)
2. [conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Conversions) that can occur when evaluating expressions (the standard conversions are most likely to trip you up, after the implicit user-defined one you already found)

Comment: yes, this is what I'm looking for i think, however now my code won't compile to show that it's a failing test...

Comment: Yeah, for strongly-typed languages we'd generally prefer to find bugs at compile time. You can always add a do-nothing overload, like `template <typename T> addItem(T&&) {}` so it will compile but have no effect.